# Is ChatGPT a viable strategy for solving the P-NP Problem?

Tags: natural-language-processing, large-language-models, automated-reasoning

According to ZDNet, it is an open question whether a transformer LLM like ChatGPT can facilitate the determination of a solution to the [P-NP Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P_versus_NP_problem). (See **[Can generative AI solve computer science's greatest unsolved problem?](https://www.zdnet.com/article/can-generative-ai-solve-computer-sciences-greatest-unsolved-problem/) (ZDNet)**) This would seem to be an attempt to mine statistical patterns of a corpus as a form of non-determinstic automated reasoning to collate a series of logical propositions that cohere to a deductively sound argument. So, the question arises is there any *a priori* justification for rejecting this particular form of generative AI as a strategy for developing a mathematical logical argument to determine an answer to the question of P-NP equivalency?

Comment: wow, how many big words ahah

Comment: Are you looking for better answer of the Nondeterministic Polynomial (time) question or an answer from Large Language Model?

Comment: @CloudCho I'm looking for analysis that confirms or disconfirms that using transformer model would a priori lead to a failure to determine if P and NP are equivalent given LLMs are prone to hallucinations.

Comment: Still hard to understand. Have you seen LLM is used in polynomial/math or boundary of non polynomial question? I found one interesting post at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/447274/a-number-theoretic-conjecture-by-chat-gpt. You may look for (or ask) how OpenAI train Chat GPT for math question.

Comment: @CloudCho Thanks. I'll take a look.